# Why is there a "Get Status" step when implementing Async APIs w/ Polling?

Tags: api, rest, asynchronous, architecture

Often times I see the following for polling:

1. Send a request and get back a unique ID.
2. Poll a "Status" endpoint, which tells the client when the request has been completed.
3. Send a request to fetch the response.

Why steps (2) and (3) can not be combined?

- If the response isn't ready yet, it'll return no response back, and some status indicating that.
- If it is ready, it'll return the response.

Why are (2) and (3) often separate steps?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is generally defined by the [HTTP 202](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/) status code, which is the HTTP protocol's mechanism of initiating asynchronous requests.

We can think of a 202 response as indicating that a *job* has been created. If and when that job executes, it may (or may not) produce some business entity. Presumably the client receiving a 202 is ultimately interested in that business entity, which may (or may not) exist in the future, but certainly does not exist *now*, hence the 202 response.

So one simple reason for returning a pointer to a job status is because the job status exists *now* and we prefer to identify things that exist now rather than things that may (or may not) exist in the future. The endpoint receiving the request may not even be capable of generating an ID for the (future) business entity.

Another reason is status codes. A status endpoint returns a custom job status capable of describing unlimited potential states in which a job can exist. These job states are beyond the scope of HTTP status codes. The standard codes defined by the [w3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) already have precise definitions; and there simply is no standard HTTP status code that means "keep polling".

Answer (score 0):

Is it ready is a boolean true/false and a response can be anything.  In general it's easier to call "is it ready" then write logic to handle true and false than to write logic to get a response, determine if the response is not ready or is the data type you need.

In this way, the logic is all client side but if you combined them you'd need to have logic on both client and server (both to say it's not ready and to handle the actual response). You could do it but keeping it separate just keeps things neater.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that they are different resources from REST perspective.

Let's examine this a bit through an example:

1. If you want to place an order then first you have to submit an order request
2. Then there is lengthy, asynchronous process in the background which checks the payment validity, the items availability in the inventories, etc.
3. If everything goes fine then there will be an order aggregate with some subelements (like order items, shipping address, etc.)

From REST perspective:

- There is a `POST /orders` endpoint to place an order
- There is a `GET /order_requests/{id}` endpoint to retrieve order request
- There is a `GET /orders/{id}` endpoint to retrieve order details

Whenever the order and all related sub-resources are created then the 2. endpoint usually responds with a [303 See Other status code](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/#:%7E:text=A%20303%20response%20indicates%20that,existing%2C%20more%20permanent%2C%20resource.) to ask the consumer to redirect to `GET /orders/{id}`.